# Facebook page access token gets invalidated for no reason

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

When the access token stops working for an unknown reason or we are close to the expiration date, we can successfully exchange our Page access token via the API endpoint for a new one, but it will have the same expiration date as the old one.

We can only reset the expiration date by requesting a new token on the developer console every time our current one gets invalidated.